# Meta-class to allow inspection of all __slots__of a class

Tags: python, object-oriented, meta-programming

If classes provide `__slots__` and at the same time inherit from another class also providing `__slots__`, there is no straightforward way to access and list each and every slot of the class. Especially when you consider chaining of inheritance.

I've written this meta-class that adds the `__all_slots__` property, listing all unique slots:

```
class MetaSlotMachine(type):
    """Meta-class that adds the attribute `__all_slots__` to a class.

    `__all_slots__`  is a set that contains all unique slots of a class,
    including the ones that are inherited from parents.

    """
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dictionary):
        super(MetaSlotMachine, cls).__init__(name, bases, dictionary)
        slots_iterator = (getattr(c, '__slots__', ()) for c in cls.__mro__)
        # `__slots__` might only be a single string, 
        # so we need to put the strings into a tuple.
        # `basestring` becomes just `str` in Python 3
        slots_converted = ((slots,) if isinstance(slots, basestring) else slots 
                                    for slots in slots_iterator)
        cls.__all_slots__ = set()
        cls.__all_slots__.update(*slots_converted)
```

Let's consider classes that inherit slots, like the following:

```
class HasSlots1(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaSlotMachine   # Python 2 Syntax
    __slots__ = ['x', 'y']

class HasSlots2(HasSlots1):
    __slots__ = 'zz'

class HasSlots3(HasSlots2):
    __slots__ = ()
```

If we create and instance via

```
myslots = HasSlots3()
```

and ask for

```
myslots.__slots__
```

Python will return the empty tuple:

```
 ()
```

However, now we can get hold of all slots via

```
myslots.__all_slots__
```

which returns all inherited slots:

```
{'y', 'x', 'zz'}
```

Is there anything flawed with the design of the meta-class? What about listing all slots based on the `__mro__` in `_get_all_slots` function?

---

**EDIT:** Revised version with gathering slots within the init function. Moreover, special care is taken about `__slots__` that only consist of a single string, like `__slots__ = '__weakref__'`.

Comment: Your edit invalidated Gareth Rees' answer, so was against the rules. See [For an iterative review, is it okay to edit my own question to include revised code?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c). However, the answer is deleted so I'm not sure now what the acceptable process is.

Comment: That was actually the reason why I edited it, otherwise his suggestions and what I found out by discussing with him would have been lost.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was no longer relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a clever use of metaclasses - in a good way. The only thing I would change is to use `set().union` over `update` (this is debatable).

Comment: Why would one prefer `mro()` over `__mro__`? From the docs (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#class.__mro__) I would assume that `mro()` is only supposed to be called once at class instantiation (to actually put the resolution order into `__mro__`).

Comment: @SmCaterpillar Ack, that's the darndest thing. Every other `__xxx__`/`xxx()` pair exists with the dunder method as the overloadable private version, but with `mro` the dunder attribute is a cache. Dastardly indeed. That said, CPython does use `mro()` itself (though less often than `__mro__`) so neither seems to be more "correct". I guess `inspect.getmro`, which just returns `cls.__mro__`, might be the "canonical" solution, but nobody seems to know about it...